# Tilde ~ makes trouble when using fstream on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, tilde

I do not exactly know whether I have an IDE/toolchain question, a Mac question or a C++ question:

I want to save a file with `ofstream`. That works as expected. But when I save to a filepath with a tilde like "~/Desktop/test.txt", `ofstream::good()` reports an error. However, I can successfully use a path like "/Users/Michael/Desktop/test.txt".

This holds for the Xcode debugger, for a run with Eclipse, as well as for a direct call of the exectuable from the console.

What is the problem with the tilde "~" here?

Comment: `~` is a feature of your actual shell, to expand the current `$HOME` directory. You can't use it with `std::fstream` neither on Mac, nor on other OS's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no path `~`, that's something that's interpreted by your shell. You will need to expand it to whatever the environment variable `HOME` is set to.

If you're calling your tool via the shell this will be expanded for you in advance. If you're within Xcode, you'll need to specify `$HOME` explicitly.